# Deployment Exception of an Apache Storm application

Tags: apache, bigdata, apache-storm, flux, apache-storm-flux

When I try to deploy the Apache Storm jar,that I have developed using Flux, I get the following error
[enter link description here](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501671743346)

My Flux file is here
[enter link description here](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501671744287)

Comment: Could you repost your screenshots on a service that doesn't require log in?

Comment: would be easier to post the stack trace here on the question.... =)